# PowerShell Error while using the AzureRM Module - HTTP Status Code: NotFound

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-data-factory

Calling all PowerShell gurus!

I'm trying to use the `Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2ActivityRun` cmdlet in the `azurerm` PowerShell Module.

When I attempt a query, it says:

`Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2ActivityRun : HTTP Status Code: NotFound
Error Code: NotFound
Error Message: Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'
Request Id: aea5f9c5-fced-4b03-929f-e071eaeb0d9e
Timestamp (Utc):10/25/2017 19:56:43
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2ActivityRun -DataFactoryName nwmovdatafactory ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2ActivityRun], ErrorResponseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.DataFactoryV2.GetAzureDataFactoryActivityRunCommand`

If I try and use the previous implementation of this cmdlet, `Get-AzureRmDataFactoryRun` it works just fine. HOWEVER, it will ALSO throw the same error as above if I do not first `Select-AzureRMSubscription`.

Furthermore, `Select-AzureRMSubscription` before running `Get-AzureRMDataFactoryV2ActivityRun` DOES NOT resolve the issue. Is there a different way I should be setting my active subscription? Or is just just a fake solution?

**EDIT:**

```
Login-AzureRMAccount -SubscriptionID SUBID

Get-AzureRmDataFactoryRun -DataFactoryName DATAFACTORY -DatasetName DATASET -StartDateTime 2017-10-25T19:34:18+00:00 -ResourceGroupName RESGROUP
```

Will work.

```
Login-AzureRMAccount -SubscriptionID SUBID

Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2ActivityRun -DataFactoryName DATAFACTORY -ResourceGroupName RESGROUP -PipelineRunId PIPELINENAME -RunStartedAfter 2017-10-25T19:34:18+00:00 -RunStartedBefore 2017-10-26T19:34:18+00:00
```

Will not work.

Comment: "Get-AzureRmDataFactoryRun : The term 'Get-AzDataFactoryRun' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. "
Currently I'm getting this error, any solution on fixing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the answer to this question is that DataFactoryv2 is an entirely different resource.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/introduction

Comment: "Get-AzureRmDataFactoryRun : The term 'Get-AzDataFactoryRun' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. " Currently I'm getting this error, any solution on fixing this

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactories/get-azurermdatafactoryrun?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Comment: Been through this doc, I did try this. But it was of no help. Getting the error which I mentioned there. I did even try to alter the version and executed still facing the same issues, even ran as admin but was of no use

Comment: Review this document and determine the proper module you need to install to have the requisite cmdlet. At the time of my answer, it was 'azurerm' . The 'azure' module did not provide this cmdlet. I am unsure now but this link should clarify for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-6.13.0